# How can I make the fixed cell at the bottom of the table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uiscrollview, user-experience

I would like to make a fixed cell at the bottom of the table view in iOS similar to that of leaderboard view of HQ trivia iOS app.

Like this:

[image: Leaderboard HQ trivia, fixed view in red rectangle]

Comment: That may be just a view positioned below the table view, and made to look like a cell.

Comment: You can add footer view to table, so it will be fixed and floating on the table view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give the impression of a fixed cell, you can simply add a `UITableView` onto a regular `UIViewController`, set its constraints so that it consumes the whole view, but stops (for example) 60px from the bottom of the screen.

Fill the remaining space with a `UIView` that has the same UI as the cell ... and thats it, the tableview will scroll, and the "cell" will always be visible at the bottom.

Comment: Is there any reason for setting it to 60px? Is that the standard value?

Comment: @SawThinkarNayHtoo no, as I said in my answer `60` was just an example, you'll need to set it to whatever suits your needs / ui

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest and cleanest way to achieve that would be to add a "cell"-like subview to the main `view` of the `viewController` and use autolayout constraints to make it fixed under the `tableView`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
    // this will make sure tableView will be placed above bottomFixedFooter, and bottomFixedFooter won't overlay any content of the tableView
    bottomFixedFooter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor),

    bottomFixedFooter.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
    bottomFixedFooter.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
    bottomFixedFooter.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

    // explicitly set the height of the bottomFixedFooter, if it does not have intrinsic content size (or its size is not calculated
    // internally using autolayout)
    bottomFixedFooter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will also try this way, for now, I am just testing with storyboard UI components.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon mentions, I put footer view at the bottom of the scroll view. I leave space for footer view so that it is fixed at the bottom with constraints.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51aY.png)