# How to make a particular Table View Cell value appear in the Footer View?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image]

Are there any tutorials, or examples to make a particular value of a table view cell from the table view return in the fixed footer view. A similar or simple concept would also be helpful. NOTE: This question is the logic part. Not for the UI design part.

Comment: Use tableView.tableFooterView = myFooterView

Comment: 1. You will need the index of the cell which is to be shown in the footer view let say Index N.
2. For showing footer view, create a XIB let say CustomXIB, load CustomXIB in the footer view.
3. Load CustomXIB in the cell with the N.(If you want to show)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the fixed cell at the bottom of the table view in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033132/how-can-i-make-the-fixed-cell-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-view-in-ios)

Comment: Why did you upload again if you already get the answer?

Comment: @Daljeet ,Vinodh I got the way for UI, I am now working on the logic part. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you storing tableview cell values?

Comment: @Daljeet I am storing one of the tableview cell values into footer view. Just like the example above. All the values will be shown as usual in the table view, and specific value will be shown in the footer view.

Comment: If you are storing it and displaying it then what is the problem. Please explain it properly in you question so you can get the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your Custom view:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
  label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
  label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
  label.text = "sawthinkar"
  customView.addSubview(label)
```

And Then add into table View footer:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

Also you can create your custom view with xib and set the required values in the custom view.